# Can a pill be used to track a person's location?

Tags: privacy, hardware, tracking

In 2017, [the FDA approved a pill with a digital sensor that can transmit information accessible by a web portal](https://www.fda.gov/news-events/press-announcements/fda-approves-pill-sensor-digitally-tracks-if-patients-have-ingested-their-medication).

If a patient takes such a pill, can it be used by hackers to track the location of this patient?

Comment: We can't answer the "more generally" section. You're asking if it is possible that someone could create something that has a certain function and then if that function could be used to explode the device. That's a lot of "ifs" and speculation about what some random person might randomly do.

Answer (score 6):

If you are asking if it is possible to create a device that can be swallowed  that can transmit *and receive* on WiFi/5G networks, then the answer is, "sure, why not?" That's not a security question, though, and is pure speculation, and has many obvious constraints on implementation (power, signal, size, lifespan, medical approval, etc.). An AirTag would appear to be more efficient...

If you are asking if the device you linked to can do that, then the answer is simpler (and can be found in the documentation you linked ...)

I think your imagination has run away with this one. The pill cannot do that and is not the threat at all.

**The app is the threat.**

No medicinal pill would have enough power to transmit/receive to/from a physically remote receiver using established communication protocols. And it wouldn't need to. The pill, as your link explains, transmits a simple signal *for detection* to a wearable patch, and the patch transmits to an app on a phone. That's a very close range for the pill and it doesn't require a receiver.

The risk, as with any wearable technology like fitness trackers, is the app, not the sensor. The app might expose the location of the user if geolocation was one of its functions.

Comment: So the reason that the pill itself  (without the app) is safe is that it does not have enough transmission power? But what if the pill transmits e.g. to a nearby wifi router, and through it, to the Internet? Or to a nearby cell-phone receiver antenna, and through it, to a cellular network? It does not sound very hard - cell phones do this all the time.

Comment: Cell phones is normally not worn inside your body. Your body is a bag of salt water. It dampens radio quite efficiently. Furthermore, cell phones are recharged regularly, such a pill would be out of battery quite fast. It's scifi. If I want to track you, I'll probably sew the tracker into your clothes, not make you swallow a large pill.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi "what if the pill transmits e.g. to a nearby wifi router" -- is it designed to do that? Does it use Wifi? Or 5g? No. You're back to speculating and into sci-fi.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi instead of speculating what *could* happen, why don't you follow the links in the article and look up the keywords to see ***what it actually does***. I found the technical datasheet in 2 minutes of poking around.

Comment: @schroeder For me, the very fact that a transmitter can be swallowed and keep transmitting from inside the body seemed utter sci-fi. I could not believe it until I read it in the FDA website. From this point, the difference between weak signal and strong signal is only quantitative.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi you still haven't read about how this one works... You've read one small fact and your imagination is running off with it and speculating against your fears. Please read how it works... You are equating "signal" with "protocol". Technology isn't magic. And neither is this technology.

Answer (score 1):

While data leaks from the app are certainly a threat, there are other threats as well.

The pill almost certainly does not have enough power (both battery and antenna) to go far.  The patch however probably links to the phone via bluetooth, and this carries the same threat any bluetooth wearable would.

It may be possible to see enough of the bluetooth traffic to identify a unique device, although the content itself should be encrypted.  However, bluetooth has a very short range, and likely the device would reduce power further to match the distance of the receiving cell phone.

Comment: I'm not sure that the patch is a specific threat if the medium is Bluetooth. The phone would be as unique to track as the patch. And that form of tracking relies on having Bluetooth antennas in close proximity, so the "tracking" is merely to see if the device was ever in range.

Comment: True.  But to use the patch, you have to enable bluetooth on the phone.

Comment: ... that's my point

Comment: Also, bluetooth from the phone can't be used to identify the patient except by some external prior association.  I don't know if the patch's bluetooth could identify the medical device itself or not.